# Maximal tensor product of quotient C*-algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

This question is from the book: C*-algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations by N.P.Brown and N. Ozawa Ex 13.3.5.

> Let C$_i$ (i=1,2) be C*-algebras with the LLP and J$_i$ be a closed
>   two-sided ideal in C$_i$. Prove that if A$_1$ = C$_1$/J$_1$ is QWEP,
>   then
>
> A$_1$ $\otimes$$_{max}$ A$_2$ =
>   C$_1$$\otimes$C$_2$/(J$_1$$\otimes$C$_2$ + C$_1$$\otimes$J$_2$）
>
> canonically. Here $\otimes$ means minimal tensor product.